# How to see wordpress posts first comment?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I show all comments of a random article on my website's homepage. But i want to show random 10 post with first comment.

i am using this code to show comments;

```
<?php 
global $withcomments;
$withcomments = true;
comments_template();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get_comments( $args ); function to get comments. Like this:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_id' => 1,
    );
    get_comments( $args );
?>
```

Here is the documentation on wordpress.org:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments